# Forcing x64 bit builds in cmake

Tags: windows, cmake, 64-bit

I have a CMake project that should not be built in 32-bit mode on x86, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to *prevent* that from happening.

Right now, it appears `cmake <path>`, by default on windows assumes a 32-bit build.

How can I make my CMake project *always* build the 64-bit variant, **without** requiring the passing of command-line arguments to CMake?

Alternatively, how can I make CMake abort if it is trying to be built as 32-bit?

Comment: There is no generic/cross-platform method to enforce 64bit builds. This is normally something the user of your project can decide. For the VS part see ["How to detect if 64 bit MSVC with cmake?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258250/how-to-detect-if-64-bit-msvc-with-cmake)

Answer (score 1):

You can add to our `CMakeLists.txt` the following code to ensure that only x64 builds are allowed:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    message("Please switch to x64 build.")
    return()
endif()
```